# javascript find correct gray for black and white effect

Tags: javascript, colors, rgb

I have a function that will convert a hex code into rgb for me:

```
function getRGB(color){    
    var matchColors = /#(\w{2})(\w{2})(\w{2})/;
    var match = matchColors.exec(color);
    var r = parseInt(match[1], 16).toString() + ",";
    var g = parseInt(match[2], 16).toString() + ",";
    var b = parseInt(match[3], 16).toString();
    answer = 'rgb(' + r + g + b + ')' ;
    return answer;
}
```

I would like to have a second function that will also take a hex code, but then modify it such that it is the equivalent gray of what the `-webit-filter: grayscale(100%)` would do.

the function would look like this:

```
function gray(color){   
    var matchColors = /#(\w{2})(\w{2})(\w{2})/;
    var match = matchColors.exec(color);
    var r = parseInt(match[1], 16).toString() + ",";
    var g = parseInt(match[2], 16).toString() + ",";
    var b = parseInt(match[3], 16).toString();
    //code to modify figure out the rgb gray value and assign it to the variable G
    answer = 'rgb(' + G + ',' + G + ',' + G + ')' ;
    return answer;
}
```

I am not sure on what determines the equivalent gray based on a color, and my research did not help much either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the grayscale formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Converting_color_to_grayscale), like this:

```
var r = parseInt(match[1], 16),
    g = parseInt(match[1], 16),
    b = parseInt(match[1], 16),
    val = Math.floor(0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b)
    answer = 'rgb(' + val + ','  + val + ',' + val + ')'

return answer
```

This is the formula:

```css
Y' =  0.2126R + 0.7152G + 0.0722B
```

### [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aHbeY/2/)

Comment: I applied you method in a jsfiddle, and it is giving me different results than the `grayscale` method. http://jsfiddle.net/aHbeY/

Comment: @RyanSaxe I fixed it and added a fiddle.