# rgb to greyscale converter

Tags: javascript, function, math, colors

Is there a function that converts rgb colours directly into their true greyscale form?

```
function rgbToGrayscale(red, green, blue) {
    const gray = []

    /* ---- CONVERSION CODE ---- */

    return gray
}

// color
const rgb = [20, 150, 240]

// grayscale conversion
const gray = rgbToGrayscale(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]) // [121, 121, 121]
```

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone can find a simple answer to this problem.

Comment: I used a "search" engine and entered "javascript rgb to greyscale converter" - and there were over 300,000 results - did none of them work for you?

Comment: You can find [several articles with examples](https://tabreturn.github.io/code/html/javascript/2017/01/26/converting_css_colour_to_greyscale.html) around internet about it. What exactly didn't work for you?

Comment: @Bravo most of them were in another language, relating to turning whole images grey or were hidden inside lots of other pointless code. I couldn't actally find a decent function out of them that was specifically for this.

Comment: So just extract the code you need.

Comment: I have looked for myself and have found a surprising lack of content regarding this. Another surprising thing is stackoverflow hardly has any questions on this specific topic either! I don't need much - just a simple function that works.

Comment: It's just what you're looking for ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/18039329/1169519

Comment: see [Problems with using a rough greyscale algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51819333/2521214)

Comment: I've got it working now and have posted an answer to explain it out. Thank you everyone for your patience and supplying me with the relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Space efficient one liners here:-

For the exact same situation as OP (thanks @Joachim):-

**Cheap:**

```js
for(gray=[];gray.length<3;gray.push([0,1,2].reduce((a,i)=>a+rgb[i],0)/3));
```

**Quite Good:**

```js
for(gray=[];gray.length<3;gray.push([.3,.59,.11].reduce((a,v,i)=>a+v*rgb[i],0)/3));
```

P.S.:

1. If you are fine with not having IE support (Check [support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_array_fill) for [fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)) for the two above, you can replace `for(gray=[];gray.length<3;gray.push` with `gray=Array(3).fill` then remove the last `)`.
2. Add `Math.round(` after `gray.push(` (or `Array(3).fill(` if you did 1) and `).toString(16).padStart(2,'0')` before the last `)` to get it in hex values.

---

For `c='#rrggbb'` to:-

**Grayscale Value:**

```js
gray=[.3,.59,.11].reduce((a,v,i)=>a+v*parseInt(c[2*i+1]+c[2*i+2],16),0)/3;
```

**Grayscale #rrggbb:**

```js
gray='#'+Array(4).join(Math.round([.3,.59,.11].reduce((a,v,i)=>a+v*parseInt(c[2*i+1]+c[2*i+2],16),0)/3).toString(16).padStart(2,'0'));
```

P.S.: Reminder that grayscale color just has the same rr, gg and bb

1. Remove `v*` to disable "Quite Good" Mode (also replace `[.3,.59,.11]` to `[0,1,2]` then remove `v,` (but I use just `v*` so that I can easily toggle between the two modes))
2. Add `x.length<6?c[i+1]+c[i+1]:` after `parseInt(` to support both '#rrggbb' and '#rgb'
3. Remove the `+1`(s) then replace the `+2` to a `+1` to support 'rrggbb' and 'rgb'
4. If you're fine without IE support (Check [support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_string_repeat) for [repeat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)) remove `Array(4).join(` and replace the last `)` with `.repeat(3)`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Spektre and @Teemu , the function now works. I found [this article](https://tannerhelland.com/2011/10/01/grayscale-image-algorithm-vb6.html) inside @Spektre 's stackoverflow link useful as well.

---

If you want a cheap greyscale colour conversion, just add the numbers together and divide it by three:

```
function rgbToGrayscale(red, green, blue) {
    const gray = (red + green + blue) / 3

    return [gray, gray, gray]
}

const gray = rgbToGrayscale(20, 150, 240) // [136.6, 136.6, 136.6]
```

But because our eyes mix up **light** and **colour**, people have found that, to us, **blue** is dimmer than **red**, and **red** is dimmer than **green**. Thus, multiple formulas have been created and refined
that balance the colours for the human eye.

This is one that I found quite good:

```js
function rgbToGrayscale(red, green, blue) {
    /* remember: if you multiply a number by a decimal between 0
    and 1, it will make the number smaller. That's why we don't
    need to divide the result by three - unlike the previous
    example - because it's already balanced. */

    const r = red * .3 // ------> Red is low
    const g = green * .59 // ---> Green is high
    const b = blue * .11 // ----> Blue is very low

    const gray = r + g + b

    return [gray, gray, gray]
}

const rgb = [20, 150, 240]
const gray = rgbToGrayscale(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2])

console.log(rgb)
console.log(gray)
```